# Height of div 100%

Tags: css, html, height, fullscreen

I want to make a div 100% height, so basically the full screen.
This, so that the background streches over the whole page.
I don't want to add the background to the body, since i want it so that if i comment out the wrapper, the page is full width. (which works by the way)

So basically my question is: how can i make the  wrapper-bg div 100% high.

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make the body height 100% because div width or height will apply only if the parent been set to a certain value 
for example if the body 100% the div height 100% will work cause the parent been determined

Comment: tried that, but it does not work for some weird reason.
Put it back again so you can see it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work as you have to make all parent elements 100%.

```
html, body {height: 100%}

.yourdiv {height: 100%}
```

Comment: You have to provide a code example then I think. Then I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with .wrapper-bg {position:fixed; top: 0px; bottom:0px}

Answer (score 0):

html,body{height: 100%}

Make sure that your parent element has height 100% and it should be positioned as relative.
Try making it absolute. Your child div strech to parent height.